# How to 'cd' to the output of the 'find' command in terminal

Tags: terminal

Pretty much I want to cd to the output of the find command:

```
find ~ -name work_project_linux
cd the_output
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the best way to execute an arbitrary command on the results of `find` is with `find -exec`. Curly braces `{}` are placeholders for the file names it finds, and the entire command ends with `+` or `\;`. For example, this will run `ls -l` on all of the files found:

```
find ~ -name work_project_linux -exec ls -l {} +
```

It doesn't work with some special commands like `cd`, though. `-exec` runs binaries, such as those found in `/usr/bin`, and `cd` isn't a binary. It's a shell builtin, a special type of command that the shell executes directly instead of calling out to some executable on disk. For shell builtins you can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
cd "$(find ~ -name work_project_linux)"
```

This wouldn't work if `find` finds multiple files. It's only good for a single file name. Command substitution also won't handle some unusual file names correctly, such as those with embedded newlines—unusual, but legal.